# Alternatives to Jars

Tags: java, jar

Hi I have been developing a java program that writes a lot of strings to text files. I need to release this program so that its executable. You can't write text files in a jar file so is there any alternatives?

I also have code that updates itself by reading a text file and making changes. These updates need to be done during running so I need a solution that does both. Thanks

Comment: You don't have to "write text files in a jar file" - you package your code into a jar, and run that jar with a path to a text file (that doesn't have to be included to a jar). Just make your program to accept that path argument.

Answer (score 1):

Files in the JARs cannot be modified while the JAR is opened. You can read them, but you don't have write access. You have to create the Files somewhere else, like in the temp or the user directory.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the "Distjubo" answer, you can ship a text file with your `jar` having some default information. On first run you can copy that file somewhere you can use `new File('sometext.txt')`, it will create file relative to your jar path (`jar-path/sometext.txt`) you can use this file for further writing and reading.